# Multiple websites on one IIS server

Tags: iis, web, server, subdomain, multiple-domains

So if I have two domains i.e. `domain1.example` and `domain2.example`, both pointing to the exact same IP address (i.e. `192.0.2.1`) on port 80.

How do I take users from `domain1.example` to one site, and users requesting from `domain2.example` to another site?

Additionally how do I set up subdomains? Someone requesting `x.domain1.example` should go to a third site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you configure the site in IIS you can assign the necessary host name in the bindings and the site will only respond to this.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I was requesting the site from www.domain1.example when I only had domain1.example binded. Binded both now and it works fine! Thanks!